# Delete IndexedDb database and recreate with button click it doesn't work after 2 or 3 click

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

With the code below, when the html button is pressed, I delete the entire database and create it from scratch. (I need this.) But after a few button clicks (2-3 click) it gets corrupted and doesn't delete and gets stuck.

Since I have autoIncrement columns, just resetting the data without deleting the database doesn't work for me. I have to delete the database and recreate it to reset it in autoIncrement.

```
        let db;

        //DELETE DATABASE
        var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("AdminDatabase");
        req.onsuccess = function () {
            console.log("Deleted database successfully");
        }
        
        //CREATE DATABASE
        const request = window.indexedDB.open("AdminDatabase", 3);
        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            db = event.target.result;
        
            if (event.oldVersion < 1) {
                var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("floors", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
            }
        
            if (event.oldVersion < 2) {
                var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("rooms", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
            }
        
            if (event.oldVersion < 3) {
                var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("components", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
                let index = objectStore.createIndex('componentFloorId, componentRoomId', ['componentFloorId', 'componentRoomId']);
                // let index2 = objectStore.createIndex('roomId', 'roomId', { unique: false});
        
            }
        
            // objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
        
        };
        
        //CONNECT DATABASE
        const request2 = indexedDB.open("AdminDatabase");
        request2.onerror = (event) => {
            console.error("Connect Db Error!");
        };
        request2.onsuccess = (event) => {
          
            db = event.target.result;

            //DB TRANSACTIONS
           ...
           ...
           ...
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the **//DB TRANSACTIONS** refreshing the page with the  **location.reload();** solved my problem.